# Trying to create an animated sliding Carousel but can not get it to loop back to the beginning slide once at the end

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, carousel

So I've been working on this Carousel Slider that uses a loop to translate all of the slides inside of a container, by the width of a single slide, over in the direction dependent on whether the left or right button is placed, and so far that works correctly. However, I am wanting with this if you are at the last slide and hit right again it will send you back to the beginning slide, same vice versa if you were at the beginning slide and hit left it would send you to the last slide. This is basically my attempt at making one of those front pages to a site carousels that also have indicators that can be clicked on to automatically move to a specific slide. I have tried to look at videos and tutorials for something of a similar effect but everything I can find so far mostly involved just layering the slides on top of each other and changing their opacity depending on the button pressed, which is great but their code appears to only work for that specific circumstance and not for a situation involving a sliding effect and not opacity.

Here is my code so far

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="carousel-container">
            <button class="slide-btn-left"><=</button>
            <button class="slide-btn-right">=></button>
            <div class="slide-container">
              <img class="slide" src="mountain-image-1.jpg" alt="beach-image-1"/>
              <img class="slide" src="mountain-image-2.jpg" alt="beach-image-2"/>
              <img class="slide" src="mountain-image-3.jpg" alt="beach-image-3"/>
              <img class="slide" src="mountain-image-4.jpg" alt="beach-image-4"/>
              <img class="slide" src="mountain-image-5.jpg" alt="beach-image-5"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        
        
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```html
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-container {
  height: 25rem;
  width: 25rem;
  position: relative;
  /* Final result will have this as overflow: hidden */
}

.slide-btn-left,
.slide-btn-right {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.slide-btn-left:hover,
.slide-btn-right:hover {
  background-color: rgb(127, 255, 212, 0.5);
}

.slide-btn-right {
  right: 0;
}

.slide-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.slide {
  height: 25rem;
  width: 25rem;
  transition: 1s;
}

/* QUERIES */

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  html {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 944px) {
  html {
    font-size: 8px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 704px) {
  html {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 544px) {
  html {
    font-size: 6px;
  }
}
```

My Javascript:

```
//prettier-ignore
carouselContainer.forEach(carContainer => {
  const carLeftBTN = carContainer.querySelector(".slide-btn-left");
  const carRightBTN = carContainer.querySelector(".slide-btn-right");
  const slideContainer = carContainer.querySelector(".slide-container");
  let slides = slideContainer.querySelectorAll(".slide");

  let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);

  let carContainerWidth = carContainer.offsetWidth / (computedStyle.fontSize.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
  let slideContainerWidth = slideContainer.offsetWidth / (computedStyle.fontSize.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
  let slideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth / (computedStyle.fontSize.match(/\d+/g)[0]);

  let currentPosition = 0;


  carLeftBTN.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("left button works");

    if (currentPosition === 0) {
      return;
    }

    currentPosition = currentPosition + slideWidth;

    for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.transform = `translateX(${currentPosition}rem)`
    }

    slides[slides.length - 1].style.transform = `translateX(-${carContainerWidth + slideWidth}rem)`;

    slides.unshift(slides.pop())

    return currentPosition;

  });

  carRightBTN.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("right button works");

    if (currentPosition === -(slideWidth * (slides.length - (carContainerWidth / slideWidth)))) {
      return;
    }

    currentPosition = currentPosition - slideWidth;

    for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.transform = `translateX(${currentPosition}rem)`;
    }

    slides[0].style.transform = `translateX(${carContainerWidth + slideWidth}rem)`;

    slides.push(slides.shift())
    

    return currentPosition;


  });
});
```

The part of the code that I've added to each buttons event listener that was intended to loop it is for the left button:

```
slides[slides.length - 1].style.transform = `translateX(-${carContainerWidth + slideWidth}rem)`;

slides.unshift(slides.pop())
```

and vice versa for the right button:

```
slides[0].style.transform = `translateX(${carContainerWidth + slideWidth}rem)`;

slides.push(slides.shift())
```

This was intended that after all the slides moved in their respective direction that the active slide so to speak would move to the opposite end of all the other slides and its index position in the array would change as well to reflect that. But this code literally does nothing and I can't understand why not so any help on how to achieve the desired effect would be appreciated as well as maybe an explanation of why that code doesn't work.

---

**edit** Your code, slightly modified to actually display images converted to a snippet with the change made to the nodelist as mentioned.

```js
const carouselContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-container");

//prettier-ignore
carouselContainer.forEach(carContainer => {
  const carLeftBTN = carContainer.querySelector(".slide-btn-left");
  const carRightBTN = carContainer.querySelector(".slide-btn-right");
  const slideContainer = carContainer.querySelector(".slide-container");
  let slides = [...slideContainer.querySelectorAll(".slide")];

  let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);

  let carContainerWidth = carContainer.offsetWidth / (computedStyle.fontSize.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
  let slideContainerWidth = slideContainer.offsetWidth / (computedStyle.fontSize.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
  let slideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth / (computedStyle.fontSize.match(/\d+/g)[0]);

  let currentPosition = 0;


  carLeftBTN.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("left button works");

    if (currentPosition === 0) {
      return;
    }

    currentPosition = currentPosition + slideWidth;

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.transform = `translateX(${currentPosition}rem)`
    }

    slides[slides.length - 1].style.transform = `translateX(-${carContainerWidth + slideWidth}rem)`;

    slides.unshift(slides.pop())

    return currentPosition;

  });

  carRightBTN.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("right button works");

    if (currentPosition === -(slideWidth * (slides.length - (carContainerWidth / slideWidth)))) {
      return;
    }

    currentPosition = currentPosition - slideWidth;

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.transform = `translateX(${currentPosition}rem)`;
    }

    slides[0].style.transform = `translateX(${carContainerWidth + slideWidth}rem)`;

    slides.push(slides.shift())


    return currentPosition;


  });
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-container {
  height: 25rem;
  width: 25rem;
  position: relative;
  /* Final result will have this as overflow: hidden */
}

.slide-btn-left,
.slide-btn-right {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.slide-btn-left:hover,
.slide-btn-right:hover {
  background-color: rgb(127, 255, 212, 0.5);
}

.slide-btn-right {
  right: 0;
}

.slide-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.slide {
  height: 25rem;
  width: 25rem;
  transition: 1s;
}


/* QUERIES */

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  html {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 944px) {
  html {
    font-size: 8px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 704px) {
  html {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 544px) {
  html {
    font-size: 6px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <button class="slide-btn-left">&lt;&lt;</button>
  <button class="slide-btn-right">&gt;&gt;</button>
  <div class='slide-container'>
    <img class='slide' src='//encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUQSv1njLBkYQaxXQz9AwvVXc9Wlfc-4ucEg' alt='mountain-image-1' />
    <img class='slide' src='//encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNoTsRV6DLwSRObz-qLOsnE1PgY3GaxDmtLw' alt='mountain-image-2' />
    <img class='slide' src='//encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXL_ym75U345CDwcGW-IUwT8UXDhTozWlTHw' alt='mountain-image-3' />
    <img class='slide' src='//encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ55xlStIKBiOZTSRFPpMLsETTBJp4U6Cc8fA' alt='mountain-image-4' />
    <img class='slide' src='//encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5VawibDVFLWLI0c31GlQ179eUclc_27KF_g' alt='mountain-image-5' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creating the above as a snippet leads to javascript errors pertaining to `slides` not being an array - using methods such as `pop` and `push`. Explicitly forcing the nodelist as an array ( ie: `let slides = [...slideContainer.querySelectorAll(".slide")];` ) yields a "sort-of" working carousel

Comment: Well, I'm confused, so slides wasn't already an array? That would explain how the pop and push methods did nothing but it doesn't quite make sense to me why the for loops worked then because they looped through it by slides index number, if it wasn't an array shouldn't it have no index? Also, you said it leads to JavaScript errors because of this but there was no error in my console. and changing slides to equal what you put there didn't change my carousel at all, it still works the same as it did initially, so what do you mean by "Sort-of" working?

Comment: `slideContainer.querySelectorAll` returns a `nodelist` rather than an array. They are similar and certain methods will work for both but not all. By "sort-of" working I got the carousel to work but not in a fashion that was pleasing to the eye.

Comment: Huh well that's something new I didn't know I will have to research about node lists then, when you say not pleasing to the eye the way it should currently look right now is the images will just be lined up all within view and then when you press right button it should slide all of them to the left and then vice versa, the left and right buttons stay in place because as mentioned above on my css the carousel container will have overflow hidden as the end result, I just have it off currently so I could see if the first image would go to the end of the line when I pressed right more clearly.

Comment: is that sort of how it looks to you or completely different?

Comment: Run the snippet in full screen mode or remove the `console.log` commands within the bttn event handlers. By not pleasing... there are gaps between slides sometimes and you get to see the image whizzing to the other end of the carousel when it reaches the end/start etc. I tried with `overflow:hidden` too and you still see the image whizz to other end

Comment: I see what you mean now, apologies the code that I copy and pasted when I asked the question earlier is not the same code I had opened up now while I was responding to you, I opened up a prior version I saved before I made that edit, so the pop and push wasn't even in the my code that's why I didn't initially see what you were talking about. Well technically now I understand why the two code snippets didn't work and how to fix it it just turns out that they wouldn't have worked the way I wanted them to anyway, appreciate the help so far Professor